# Rank of a 5 by 4 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *A* be  $5\times4$ matrix with real entries such that space of all solutions of the system  $AX^{t}=[1,2,3,4,5]^{t}$ is given by $\{[1+2s,2+3s,3+4s,4+5s]^{t}:s\in \mathbb{R}\}$ then what is the rank of the matrix $A$.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the null space is one dimensional (based on the fact that the solution set has one parameter $s$), by rank-nullity theorem, the rank will be $3$.

**added explanation:**

The solution set for the given for the given system $Ax=b$ can be written as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3\\4
\end{bmatrix}
+s\begin{bmatrix}
2\\3\\4\\5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The first vector is a particular solution, whereas the second vector represents the solution for the homogeneous system $Ax=0$. This is how you know that null space is spanned by ONE vector, hence is one dimensional.

Comment: How null space has dimension one?

Comment: how exactly we can say that null space has one dim...please explane a little more.

Comment: @YOGESH please see added explanation.

Comment: yes you are right....

Comment: my confusion is that how exactly we can say that last expression is solution of corresponding hom system?/

Comment: can we show that yes it is solution of the homogeneous system?

Comment: @YOGESH you need to familiarize with the basic theory of linear systems. Please read a good book and try to learn how the solutions are written for a system. This forum is used for giving helpful pointers but not necessarily teaching the basics of a subject.

Comment: i think because of your concept of one parameter we can say that null space has dim one?

Comment: ok sir thanks a lot..

Comment: @YOGESH here is a link that can be useful for you http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/General_%3D_Particular_%2B_Homogeneous

Answer (score -2):

You can find the rank of a matrix by using elementary row operations to put the matrix into row-reduced echelon form and then, the rank will simply be equal to the number of non-zero rows. Hope that helps you

Comment: But matrix is not given in exactly...